# can loggly be used to store activity streams

Tags: social-networking, feed

Would the loggly service give credible performance for writing and retrieving activity streams?  It seems like it would be good for writing json objects that represent an activity for each user, but what is its performance like in terms of retrieving those objects for a particular user?  Can I query for things like get me the last 100 activity items for a user, or activity for the last week for a given user?  Can I do things like sum of all activity items of a particular type?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is using loggly as a NoSQL db.
I would suggest using your own DB since you are writing query logic on top of storage.

Maybe ravenhq.com is a better fit if you dont want to manage IT & storage for a full db server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an activity stream API with cloud storage, Collabinate (http://www.collabinate.com) may be what you're looking for.  It's build for high performance aggregation of activity streams into feeds that can be retrieved to any length.

Full disclosure: I am the creator of Collabinate.